# 2 versions of jQuery UI's on the same page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, uidatepicker

Well,

I have this page where you need to select the date range and where you need to move some items (a nested list).

For the date range I've chosen the old jquery date picker which was great because it gave the possibility to choose the range intelligently and easily. (The new one does not have this feature anymore) and for the moving (reordering) of items I'm using jquery sortable nested list.

The problem is that the old jquery datepicker works with the old jquery ui and the sortable nested list works wth the new jquery ui and when I include both of them Firefox crashes.

I've tried something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j$132 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

but still no luck. Can anybody tell me a jquery date range picker (a newer one) or a jquery sortable nested list (that works with the old sortable) or simply how I could include 2 versions of jquery UI on the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved the problem using http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker

Answer (score 1):

I would not advice including multiple versions of jquery ui. I've included multiple versions of jquery itself by mistake in the past and it's very very unpredicatable. So I'm guessing you'll have similar trouble with jquery-ui as well.

I've come across a control by the filament group that wraps the jquery-ui date picker with features for ranges, it might help:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/

Comment: It's not the kind of date range picker I want. I want only one calendar.. :-<

Comment: Do you have a link (perhaps on http://jsfiddle.net/) to an example of the structure of the old jquery datepicker you're looking for?